# Why am I getting infinite loop?

Tags: c++, cin

```
int main()
{
  unsigned short wC;

  while(1)
  {
    cout << "Enter the Value"<<endl;
    cin >> wC;
    if(wC < 0 || wC > 3)
    {
      cout << "Wrong value, Please Enter again" << endl;
    }
    else break;
  }// end of while

  cout << "The value is : " << wC << endl;
}//end of main
```

In the above code, when I give value in range of short `0xffff` it work fine.
And comes out of loop and print the value only when user has given value for `wC` in between 0 to 3 otherwise prompt message to Enter again and wait for user's input.

But if value entered for `wC` is more than `0xffff` then it goes to Infinite Loop.

I think it is due to value still exist in input `cin` buffer or what?
Please help and provide some solution(hint), so that it should work.

NOTE : User is free to give any integer value. the code has to filter it out.
Using `g++` compiler on `Ubuntu/Linux`... and `sizeof(unsigned short int) = 2 bytes`

Comment: That's because `cin` is in a bad state after an error, and won't receive any input until you clear the bad bit.

Comment: Since `wC` is unsigned it can never be less than zero so there's no point checking for that.

Answer (score 2):

If input fails, either because what you entered isn't an integer at all or because it overflows or underflows the target type, `cin` goes into an error state (`cin.good()` returns false) and any further read operation is a no-op. Put calls to `cin.ignore` (to clear out remaining input) and `cin.clear` (to reset error flags) into the loop.

Even then, you can still run into an issue if the user enters EOF (Ctrl+D on Unix, Ctrl+Z on Windows). You need your loop to understand that part too and break out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  unsigned short value;
  cout << "Enter the value (0-3):" << endl;
  while(true) {
    cin >> value;
    if (!cin || value < 0 || value > 3) {
      if (cin.eof()) {
        cout << "End of input, terminating." << endl;
        return 0;
      }
      cout << "Bad input, try again (0-3):" << endl;
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
  }
  cout << "The value is: " << value << endl;
}
```

Of course that is one hell of a lot of code just to input one number. You can practice coming up with good interfaces by trying to write a function that deals with this stuff for you.

Comment: hey, thanks +1, can you please elaborate a bit. which one will be better to use .. `ignore` or `clear`

Comment: @Omkant you will need to call `clear` *and* `ignore`; `ignore` doesn't clear the error flags.

Comment: And you have to call `clear` first, because otherwise the `ignore` will be ignored. I almost made this mistake in the code above.